# On page CSS to override server added value

Tags: html, css

We have had a site re-designed by a company who also maintains and hosts it, as well as providing us with our CRM system. The issue I am facing is they add a bit of a backlink to the footer, which I am unable to edit as its not part of the page until the server generates it.

I would like to use On Page CSS to style this to white, or completley remove it. Either is fine

```
<span style="width: 100%; text-align: center; display: block; color: #999999; font-family: verdana; font-size: 7pt;margin-bottom:4px;">Powered by <a style="color: #999999;" href="http://www.prospectsoft.com/ecommerce" target="_blank">ProspectSoft eCommerce</a> and <a style="color: #999999;" href="http://www.prospectsoft.com/crm" target="_blank">CRM</a></span>
```

The above is the code I can see when I look at the source of the page in Firefox. I cannot see this code in the editor they provide, however I can edit the css files.

Is it possible to use on page CSS to style this out?

Comment: Please show the parent element it's in. Is it the last element of the `<body>`, is it inside the `<footer>` element?

Comment: That may be a violation of the terms of service.

Comment: I made my MD aware of the fact it will violate ToS and he told me to go ahead anyway

Comment: <script src="/footer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <span style="width: 100%; text-align: center; display: block; color: #999999; font-family: verdana; font-size: 7pt;margin-bottom:4px;">

        Powered by 

        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.prospectsoft.com/ecommerce" style="color: #999999;"></a>

         and 

        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.prospectsoft.com/crm" style="color: #999999;"></a>
    </span>

</div>
::after

Comment: Sorry if the URL's ain't allowed. Also the footer.js only contains the code for the address, phone number etc displayed on bottom of page. It makes no reference to the "Powered By"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in my mind with pure CSS, no since there doesn't seem to be something unique to reference it by.

## Alternate Solution:

If you can use Jquery it should be relatively easy though.

Do following in head:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function () {
$('footer').child().hide();
});
</script>
```

Depending on the build of the page you should be able to isolate that HTML element. For instance, if that span is the only element in the

```
<footer>
```

tag, you could simply use:

```
$('footer').hide();
```

**Note:** They may already be referencing jquery, which means you could just do the code.

## One More:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("a:contains('ProspectSoft eCommerce')").parent().hide();
});
```

Will delete all parents of anchor tags that contain that text though, so be careful.

## EDIT:

```
$("span:contains('Powered by')").hide();
```

Comment: Hey. This seems like a great solution, I am going to try it now. The only thing on the whole page that contains the word "Powered By" is what I am trying to get rid. So using your 2nd solution and changing to ("a:contains('Powered By')") would work?

Comment: Also when referencing jquery its <script -->src<-- > </script>, not source. Made that edit as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much

Comment: I vehemently disagree with this solution. This can ABSOLUTELY be done with CSS alone.

Comment: This worked perfect for me, but as an addition to your answer, it was calling insecure version of jquery. My site already had a secure version, so I removed <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> and it now does exactly what I wanted it to do and also gets rid of the insecure element warning on my page. Thanks v much Terrance00

Answer (score 0):

In line CSS will typical override stylesheets declared in the document head.

If you find certain properties remain stubbornly unaffected, try using the "`!important`" modifier.

Example:

```
color: #ff0000 !important;
```

Beyond this, I can't give you any further advice given that you haven't specified exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Hi Jiminy. I can't add anything to the HTML markup I pasted above. This is added by the server it is hosted on. I want to use on page ccs, or even in the css file to style it out. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes absolutely. If you can add custom CSS, then you're golden. Simply use the "!important" attribute for anything that won't override.

Answer (score 0):

Not good looking but works:

`div span, span a { color: #FFF !important; }`

Bad thing is you would have to set the color to all other similar nests "div span" and "span a"